Route Inspection w/ OSMnx
What's the best way to use route inspection algorithms (Chinese mailman, multi depot vehicle routing) with OSMnx data? Are their existing functions inside of OSM or another lib that already fill this use case?
OSMnx looks like an amazing library it fill so many of my use cases and if there isn't currently an 'official' solution I'd love to contribute one.
Let me know:)

OSMnx builds NetworkX graphs. You can refer to NetworkX's documentation for full details on available algorithms and analyses.
